# Dispose WaitHandle for basic thread synchronization

Tags: c#, multithreading, waithandle

According to documentation, WaitHandle in .NET should be explicitly/implicitly disposed. However, I'm having trouble achieving this for the following basic synchronization task:

- a time consuming task is being executed on a thread.
- the main thread waits for the task to complete for a predefined time-period. The main thread must proceed if a. the task is completed or b. the timeout occurred.

Here my attempt at using an AutoResetEvent object:

```
using(var waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false)){
    var worker = new Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            TimeConsumingTask();
            waitHandle.Set(); //throws System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {...}
    }) {IsBackground = true};
    worker.Start(); //start worker

    const int waitTimeInMs = 5000; 
    var signaled = waitHandle.WaitOne(waitTimeInMs);//block main thread here. 
    if (!signaled)
    { //if timed out
       worker.Interrupt();
    }
}
```

There is an obvious race condition where the main thread wait times out and disposes the wait handle object which causes ObjectDisposedException exception. Is there any other way that I set this up so that the handle is properly disposed and without causing the exception?

Comment: Why is the main thread handling the wait object?  It exists for signaling to/from the thread - the thread should own it.

Comment: how does this resolve the race condition? if waithandle is disposed in the worker thread before main thread calls waitOne, waitOne will throw same exception.

Comment: Can you switch to `Task`? Makes many things easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, there's no decent way to do this.  Do note up front that you painted yourself into that corner by essentially leaving a thread running wild, nothing particularly nice about that.

But you are focusing on the much smaller problem.  The Thread class itself is already a resource hog, consuming a megabyte of VM and five synchronization objects.  But it has no Dispose() method.  This was courageous design, there's just no decent way to call the method.

Disposing is *optional*, nothing that dramatic happens when you don't call it.  The class has got your back, it has a finalizer that ensures that the native operating system resource will be released.  Which *will* run, eventually, just not as quickly as you'd like.

Compare this to a class with a less courageous design, the Task class has a Dispose() method.  Which, like Thread, is almost as hard to call.  The [guidance from the .NET gurus](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/25/10287435.aspx) is to just not bother.

Same here.

Comment: thanks that was useful. re comment about leaving threads running wild, what's the best practice there?

Comment: Not leaving them running wild of course.  I have no insight whatsoever in why you thought it was important.  If it is exceptional for a thread to not complete in a reasonable time then you should raise an exception.  It is the courageous thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

The waithandle is disposing because your using scope invokes a new thread an returns immediately,  causing the waithandle to dispose.

What you should do is explicitly call dispose after you finish your work instead of your using statement:

```
waitHandle.WaitOne(waitTimeInMs);
if (!signaled)
{ //if timed out
   worker.Interrupt();
}
waitHandle.Dispose();
```

Comment: Set() can still throw an exception if Dispose() is called on waitHandle before worker has a chance to be interrupted. The race condition still stands with an explicit dispose call.