# How to safely dispose of a WaitHandle?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winapi, event-wait-handle

Consider this code:

```
volatile EventWaitHandle waitHandle;

// Thread1, represents an IO-bound worker thread:
while (true) {
  waitHandle?.Set();
}

// Thread 2, represents some "main" thread:
waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(true);
waitHandle.WaitOne();
Sleep(1000);  // To simulate some work.
// Close the wait handle; we're done with it.
EventWaitHandle handle = waitHandle;
waitHandle = null;
handle?.Close();
```

The null coalescing operator means that accessing waitHandle is safe from thread1. And the atomicity of setting reference types (plus it's marked volatile) mean that accessing waitHandle after setting it is safe from thread 2.  AutoResetEvent (and indeed all classes which inherit from EventWaitHandle) [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent?view=netcore-3.1#thread-safety) it's threadsafe.  So naively this should all be threadsafe.

However, if thread 1 is inside the Set() method when Thread2 Closes the handle could this lead to undefined behavior/race condition?  Looking at the code in the .NET reference implementation I don't see any obvious mechanism that would prevent this.

Close calls Dispose, which [calls Close](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/c77a98d5e06b0815.html) on the SafeWaitHandle, which eventually [calls CloseHandle](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/6c45abb6fce45aad.html) in the WinAPI.  Set calls [SetEvent](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/63f3d76fa45ccc3d.html) in the WinAPI.  In both cases I don't see any other obvious threading mechanisms, so it seems possible that I could end up in a situation where one thread is calling CloseHandle on the same handle another is calling SetEvent on. If SetEvent is called first there's no problem but if CloseHandle is called first maybe that would cause problems?

I've tried reading the documentation around [CloseHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle) and [SetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-setevent) but it's still not clear to me.

Is this a potential race condition/undefined behavior or not?  If it is a problem, what's the correct way to handle it?  I could always wrap calls to Set and Close in a lock but it seems strange to wrap access to a mutex in another synchronization mechanism.

For reference I've found this [older question asking essentially the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23041180/250960).  The guidance there was to not Close the handles after all, but the blog linked is a dead link and leaving IDisposable objects hanging without cleaning up after them leaves a bad taste in my mouth.  Is this still the proper way to handle this?

Comment: Any reason you can't use the .net native synchronization tools? They will work better in most cases where you don't need interop.

Comment: I'd take a step back and ask why you have something calling `Close` at all on something that may still be in use by other threads. Some *one* thing needs to assume ownership of this object, and that something must know enough about other lifetimes to know when nothing else is using the handle and then close it.

Comment: @Mgetz I am using .net synchronization tools.  It's just that those tools wrap WinAPI calls under the hood.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Conceptually there's some work that might need doing.  These works' lifetimes are shorter than either of the two threads (and there's only one work active at a time).  At the moment I'm gating access to that work with a WaitHandle, with the idea that I'd replace the WaitHandle as the work items die and get replaced.  It's probably worth a whole discussion around if that's a good idea or not, but it's probably outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Closing an invalid handle raises a 1st chance exception that you catch when debugging - 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified. You usually *wait* on these events (or on thread handle for that matter). You don't close them expecting everything went well. You don't use arbitrary timeout (Sleep) except in WaitXXX methods.

Comment: @SimonMourier I'm not sure I fully understand, but the Sleep(1000) is just simulating some work.  You can imagine it's waiting on the sets from thread1 in a normal producer/consumer pattern, except at some point it decides to close out the handle.

Comment: I can imagine lots of things, but I'm looking at your sample code. "At some point it decides to close the handle". This point in time should always be done after a wait that either succeeded or timed out. In the normal course of operation if you have waits that succeed and the code is correct, there's no reason why you should close a handle that's still in use.

Comment: @SimonMourier I don't see how it matters if there's a wait or not, but I've updated the code to include a WaitOne().

Comment: Your code is not realistic. You should wait for the thread handle itself or an event that the thread sets to say 'I'm finished". And if the thread is designed to never ever finish (like in your sample), that's another problem.

Comment: @SimonMourier It sounds like you're saying that I should protect WaitHandle with another synchronization mechanism?  If so, you should write that as an answer and justify why.

Comment: Use tools at the highest level of abstraction possible to solve your problems.  You have a producer and a consumer.  Don't deal with wait handles, use tools specifically designed for producer/consumer models, such as TPL Dataflow, since your work is asynchronous. (Or tools like BlockingCollection, if your workers were synchronous.)  That will result in code much easier to read and write, as the management of lower level synchronization mechanisms is already done for you, as you only need to specify what the actual business logic of your producers/consumers is.

Comment: Even if, for some reason, you wanted to go all low-level manual synchronization, a monitor (`lock`, `PulseAll`, `Wait`) or `SemaphoreSlim` would still be simpler and more lightweight than OS events, while `Task` for async I/O is more lightweight than explicit threads. But I'm in full agreement with Servy that you probably shouldn't be writing code like this at all; the return on cooking this sort of stuff manually as opposed to using higher level libraries is low and decreasing every day.

Comment: You could do it like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/qnxMKw88 but again it really depends on your context and your real scenario. In C# with async/await constructs and Tasks, you often don't really need this kind of code any more, especially when there are other processors involved (network card, etc.) and you can use async IO. https://www.softwaresessions.com/episodes/async-programming-and-tcp-sockets-in-csharp-with-stephen-cleary/

Comment: Yes, there is a race condition. Why not create the Event before either thread starts and close it after they both finish?